# Mysql case statement with aggregate function (only use aggregate if it will work)

Tags: mysql

I have this query that was working until I realized that if the table is empty, `max` doesn't work. I check for the `position` for a user and then insert a row which has a position that is one higher. How can I setup a case where if there are no rows with the appropriate user_id, I insert a row with the position being 1? I have attempted to make a case statement but it didn't work, I'm drowning in Mysql syntax.

**Below Is the original**

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
    insert into 
        dashboard_data 
    (position, user_id)
        select 
            max(position) + 1, 
            :userid 
        from 
            dashboard_data 
        where 
            user_id = :userid
");
```

**And here is my misguided attempt at a case statement**

```
insert into 
        dashboard_data 
    (position, user_id)
        select 
            case 
                when exists 
                    max(position)
                then 
                    max(position) + 1 
                else 
                    1
            end case,
            :userid 
        from 
            dashboard_data 
        where 
            user_id = :userid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use IFNULL, which will allow you to replace a NULL value with something else.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: Worked beautifully, I had got it to work with 10 lines of junk but this brought it down to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
insert into dashboard_data(position, user_id)
    select coalesce(max(position), 0) + 1, 
           :userid 
    from dashboard_data 
    where user_id = :userid;
```

Comment: +1 from me, already used @marshall's answer and it's working though.

Comment: @CraigPatrickLafferty Coalesce is better if you have a chain of possible NULL values, otherwise they operate similarly.   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: I agree, I happen to only have one possible value though. I will be sure to use this in the future.